# Material-UI- Warning

Tags: arrays, dart

I'm using Material UI tabs for the first time in my project, everything works fine but there is one error in console while running the project here is:

Warning: Failed prop type: Material-UI: `overlap="rectangle"` was deprecated. Use `overlap="rectangular"` instead.

Answer (score 16):

If you use the `Badge` component add or change the value of the `overlap` property to `rectangular`.

```
<Badge overlap="rectangular" .../>
```

The `error` comes from the `Badge.js`

```
 if (overlap === 'rectangle') {
  throw new Error('Material-UI: `overlap="rectangle"` was deprecated. Use `overlap="rectangular"` instead.');
}
```

I hope that will give some peace of mind to some ;)

Answer (score 3):

I suffered from same warning recently. If you use a Badge component and you're probably on react 18, then you you should pass the overlap prop to the Badge component just like @bluehipy mentioned

```
<Badge overlap="rectangular"></Badge>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solve this problem by simply add props in the Badge Component which we are using everywhere.

[Click here for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMMPw.png)

```js
<Badge overlap="rectangular">
  <ShoppingCartOutlined />
</Badge>
```

Answer (score 1):

Must be due to conflicting versions of the library, I've changed as many imports starting with `"@material-ui/..."` as possible with the newer one starting with `"@mui/material"` and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from the same phenomenon. Are you using `@material-ui/data-grid`?

I solved it by using `@mui/x-data-grid`.

One thing to note is that you need to downgrade react.

```
$ npm i react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0
```

After typing this one.

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @mui/x-data-grid
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Execute this command.

After that, change the import.

```
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'
```

Sorry if the error is not resolved.